# Mongodb aggregation, get expected result on groupBy without hard-coding categories

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My objective is to write an efficient query, that with the given input, gives me the expected output. I have some working solution, but all "types" are "manually" written, so I guess I'm looking for help to get the same output but in a different way.

**input**

| reportId | type | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | "fish" | 4 |
| A | "fish" | 2 |
| A | "cow" | 0 |
| B | "fish" | 2 |
| B | "tuna" | 1 |
| B | "bird" |  |

**Expected output**

```js
[
  {
    reportId: "A",
    totalCount: 3,
    totalWeight: 6,
    fishCount: 2,
    tunaCount: 0,
    cowCount: 1,
    birdCount: 0
  },
  {
    reportId: "A",
    totalCount: 3,
    totalWeight: 2,
    fishCount: 1,
    tunaCount: 1,
    cowCount: 0,
    birdCount: 1
  },
   
]
```

**Partial "hard-coded" solution**

What I have been doing so far is to create 2 group-by steps: It kind of get's the job done, but in my real use-case there are a lot of types, and therefore the group-stages are very long.

```
[
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { reportId: "$reportId", type: $type },
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      totalWeight: { $sum: "$weight" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.reportId",
      totalCount: { $sum: "$totalCount" },
      totalWeight: { $sum: "$totalWeight" },
      fishCount: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: {
            "if": { $eq: ["$_id.type", "fish"] },
            then: "$count",
            else: 0
          }
        }
      },
      tunaCount: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: {
            "if": { $eq: ["$_id.type", "tuna"] },
            then: "$count",
            else: 0
          }
        }
      },
      // <== And here I have a count blog for each type. Can I get the same result in a better way?
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I will focus to the second part, which is the difficult one. I don't know whether there is a shorter and better solution, but this one should work:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unset: "_id"
  },
  {
    $set: {
      data: {
        "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$reportId",
      data: {
        $push: "$data"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      data: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$data",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      data: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$data",
          cond: {
            $not: {
              $in: [
                "$$this.k",
                [
                  "totalCount",
                  "totalWeight"
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      data: {
        $push: "$data"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: "$data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GtCWH2cZqLt)

Comment: Amazin job, it's almost there - I need the data grouped by the reportId. But I don't know if it's simpler/better. Currently looking into the $accumulator fn